# How do I detect if SELinux is enabled in an android application?

Tags: android, selinux

I'm trying to use the SecureRandom workaround that Google posted in my android application:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html

This work around involve writing to (and reading from) /dev/urandom. However, it looks like Samsung has enabled SELinux in such a way that prevents applications from accessing /dev/urandom.

I don't have one of these devices, so it is a little hard for me to test solutions, other than to push out attempts at workarounds on the Android market, but it seems like this is not an error that I can trap with a try catch block. It also appears that File.canRead and canWrite return true. You can see my attempts at workaround in the supportedOnThisDevice method in the following class:
[PRNGFixes.java](https://github.com/bpellin/keepassdroid/blob/f2158ad1cf606635a3f6f5dcb63e833f2e573042/src/com/keepassdroid/compat/PRNGFixes.java)

I'm looking for a reliable way to detect if I am an such a device, and if so, not apply the Google SecureRandom workaround.

Answer (score 3):

This is my way to check if SELinux is in enforce-mode - can be done via any Shell-script, not depending on RootTools:

```
private static boolean isSELinuxEnforcing() {
    try {
        CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(1, "getenforce");
        RootTools.getShell(false).add(command).waitForFinish();
        boolean isSELinuxEnforcing = command.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("enforcing");
        return isSELinuxEnforcing;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've heard Samsung is starting to ship devices with the SELinux policy set to Enforce, but I don't know if it's true or not. As far as I know most devices on 4.3 still have it set to permissive.

According to Google, ["SELinux reinforcement is invisible to users and developers, and adds robustness to the existing Android security model while maintaining compatibility with existing applications."](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/enhancements43.html) So you may need to check the system properties or test it through a shell to find out for sure.

If you can get someone to send you their build.prop you may be able to catch it by comparing their ro.build.selinux property via `System.getProperty("ro.build.selinux")`,
but you'll also want to verify you're able to access it more directly in case it is unreliable or getProperty() for that is broken in future updates.

Root (System user on SELinux) is another option when available, but either way a shell based solution is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.getProperty("ro.build.selinux")
```

Did not work for me on Samsung S4 Android 4.3. So I wrote this

```
private static final int JELLY_BEAN_MR2 = 18;

public static boolean isSELinuxSupported() {
        // Didnt' work
        //String selinuxStatus = System.getProperty(PROPERTY_SELINUX_STATUS);
        //return selinuxStatus.equals("1") ? true : false;

        String selinuxFlag = getSelinuxFlag();

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(selinuxFlag)) {
            return selinuxFlag.equals("1") ? true : false;
        } else {
            // 4.3 or later ?
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }       
}

public static String getSelinuxFlag() {
        String selinux = null;

        try {
            Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
            Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class);
            selinux = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.build.selinux");
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

        return selinux;
}
```

Comment: What are the return values of this method?

Comment: isSELinuxSupported returns true (if SELinux is present) or false

Comment: SELinux is enforced on some of my devices but `ro.build.selinux` has no value so this is not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to the frameworks

```
import android.os.SELinux;

SELinux.isSELinuxEnforced();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most devices as as of Jellybean MR2 and onwards will have SELinux enabled on their devices, but if you are working with OEMs or doing platform work this might not necessarily be true.

The method I am using to verify is with the getenforce shell command:

```
public boolean isSeLinuxEnforcing() {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getenforce");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "OS does not support getenforce");
        // If getenforce is not available to the device, assume the device is not enforcing
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    String response = output.toString();
    if ("Enforcing".equals(response)) {
        return true;
    } else if ("Permissive".equals(response)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "getenforce returned unexpected value, unable to determine selinux!");
        // If getenforce is modified on this device, assume the device is not enforcing
        return false;
    }
}
```

It appears that most devices are only writing a system property for selinux if they **aren't** running in enforcing status. You can additionally check the property: **ro.boot.selinux** to see if the Kernel passed in the permissive parameter on your current build.